# 100 hz Square Wave of 50% duty cycle in digital pin 3 and verifying with pin 4

Tags: arduino-uno

I am stuck on this for a while, I am trying to generate a 100 hz square wave with 50% duty cycle in pin 3 and trying to verify it with wire at pin 4; I am getting 64000 but not 100 in serial monitor.

```
#define LEDPIN 3

uint16_t val2= pulseIn(4, HIGH);

ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect) { digitalWrite(LEDPIN, !digitalRead(LEDPIN)); }
void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
pinMode(LEDPIN, OUTPUT);
// initialize Timer1 (the 16-bit timer) using channel A output compare
noInterrupts(); // disable global interrupts
// TIMER 1 for interrupt frequency 100 Hz:
cli(); // stop interrupts
TCCR1A = 0; // set entire TCCR1A register to 0
TCCR1B = 0; // same for TCCR1B
TCNT1 = 0; // initialize counter value to 0
// set compare match register for 100 Hz increments
OCR1A = 19999; // = 16000000 / (8 * 100) - 1 (must be <65536)
// turn on CTC mode
TCCR1B |= (1 << WGM12);
// Set CS12, CS11 and CS10 bits for 8 prescaler
TCCR1B |= (0 << CS12) | (1 << CS11) | (0 << CS10);
// enable timer compare interrupt
TIMSK1 |= (1 << OCIE1A);
sei(); // allow interrupts
//TCCR1A = 0; // Timer/Counter Control Register 1A
//TCCR1B = 0; // (both control registers need to be configured)
//// set compare match register to desired timer count:
//OCR1A = 15624; // Output Compare Register 1A (i.e., for channel A)
//TCCR1B |= (1 << WGM12); // CTC (Clear Timer on Compare Match) mode
//TCCR1B |= (1 << CS10); // for 1,024 prescaler; UNO has a 16 MHz clock
//TCCR1B |= (1 << CS12);
//TIMSK1 |= (1 << OCIE1A); // enable timer compare interrupt
interrupts(); // enable global interrupts:
}
void loop() {
uint16_t val = OCR1A/8;

ICR1 = val -1;
OCR1A = val/2 - 1 ; // 50% duty cycle for pin 3
//OCR1B = val/2 - 1 ; // 50% duty cycle for pin 4
//uint16_t val2= pulseIn(4, HIGH);
Serial.print(val2);
delay(1000);
Serial.print("\n");

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You wrote:

```cpp
uint16_t val2 = pulseIn(4, HIGH);
```

It makes no sense to call this here, as the timer has not been
initialized. You probably cannot expect anything but a timeout in this
context.

```cpp
noInterrupts();
cli();
```

These two are synonyms. No need to repeat yourself. Actually, no need to
block interrupts at all.

```cpp
sei();
interrupts();
```

Ditto.

```cpp
OCR1A = 19999; // = 16000000 / (8 * 100) - 1
```

This is supposed to fire interrupts at 100 Hz. But if you want a
100 Hz output signal, you should fire the interrupts at 200 Hz
(two interrupts per cycle). Thus:

```cpp
OCR1A = 9999; // = (16 MHz / 8) / (2 * 100 Hz) - 1
```

Then,

```cpp
// Set CS12, CS11 and CS10 bits for 8 prescaler
TCCR1B |= (0 << CS12) | (1 << CS11) | (0 << CS10);
```

This is configuring Timer 1 for an external clock source. If you
want ÷8 prescaler, you should only set bit `CS11`. Check the datasheet.

```cpp
uint16_t val = OCR1A/8;
ICR1 = val -1;
OCR1A = val/2 - 1 ; // 50% duty cycle for pin 3
```

This doesn't make any sense to me. Why are you setting `ICR1`? Why are
you changing `OCR1A` although it was already configured in `setup()`?
You can remove all this. Here is the `loop()` I used for testing:

```cpp
void loop() {
    Serial.println(pulseIn(3, HIGH));
    delay(1000);
}
```

And it repeatedly printed `4955`, which is quite close to the expected
value (namely 5000).

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: `TCCR1B |= (0 << CS12) | (1 << CS11) | (0 << CS10);` is divide by 8.  It is shifting a couple zeros.  It is like `TCCR1B |= (0b010 << CS10);` but I like the `0b010<<CS10` format better if you are trying to document the three clock select bits.